# Accessing MQ in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I am writing a code in c# .NET which connects to IBM websphere. When tried to connect to queue manager i am getting the error:

> 2035 (07F3) (RC2035): MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED error message.

But with same details(Host name,port number,channel name,queue manager) i am able connect to queue manager and queue using java code.

What could be the reason?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to MQ via bindings mode, the MQ Client library uses the UserID that you are running under.

When you connect to MQ via client mode, the MQ Client library uses:

- the UserID that is set in your code or
- the value (UserID) set in the channel's MCAUSER field.

You should read up on MQ security and make sure you implement it correctly. Talk to your company's MQAdmin.

Comment: I have installed IBM client v7 connecting to websphere. I am able connect to queue manager now but not to queue getting  same error 2035(NOT AUTHORIZED).This error could be from admin side or from my application side.

Comment: Its the same MQ security issue.